# Java -Xss6G argument not preventing StackOverflowError, no RAM used

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

The java program in question is highly recursive (the infamous Ackermann function) and will call itself billions of times. It does work in c but not in java, even when using -Xss6G to add stack size and using -Xsx6G (or similiar). While that might just not be enough space, the RAM is actually not even used as visible in the Ubuntu system manager and when there are about 23 thousand instances (no matter the allocated memory) of the method present at a time java just gives up. What is the cause of this / why is the Overflow still happening?

```
ack(4,1)

public static int ack (int m, int n) {
    if(recs % 131072 == 0) System.out.println("Function call number "+recs);//not the code used for the 23 thousand-number. Just for tracking how fast the code operates
    recs++;
    int ans;
    if(m==0) ans = n+1;
    else if(n == 0) ans = ack(m-1,1);
    else ans = ack(m-1, ack(m,n-1));
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: That's weird, with -Xss4G I could get a result on my side for ack(4, 1)

Comment: The more relevant measure is the stack depth, not the number of calls (`recs`).

Comment: Which JVM are you running on?

Comment: Why not use a non recursive implementation of the function?

Comment: "-Xss4g" is not sufficient for my VM 1.8.0_40 (64bit). The program works with "-Xss5g" for me on Windows 7. Does the Ubuntu system limit the process/thread stack size somehow?

Comment: @andy: yes i know, the code in the question is not the one i used to determine the 23 thousand-number.

Comment: @Esko Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

Comment: @Konrad all i know is that it worked in C, never heard of such behavior in linux. Also as far as I know this is an example for code that is only possible recursively :)

Comment: @Konrad Oh, interesting, thank you very much for actually trying that one out :)

Comment: @Esko Java 8_66-b17 that is

Comment: wfm with `java -Xss4g Ack` on Mac OS X Yosemite with Java `"1.8.0_74"`